# How to get the key of a specific value, in Python, if the value is an element of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

A dictionary with the Keys being Countries and the Values being Lists of Cities in that country is given. At the input, a list of random Cities is given. At the output, the list of the given cities must be splinted in different lists depending on the country.

Example:
**INPUT**:

```
    CountryDict = {
    "Spain" : ["Madrid", "Barcelona"],
    "Italy" : ["Rome", "Venice", "Milan"],
    "Germany": ["Munich"],
    "UK": ["London", "Liverpool"]
    }
    CityList = ["Venice", "Liverpool", "Madrid", "Barcelona"]
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Italy:
["Venice"]

UK:
["Liverpool"]

Spain:
["Madrid", "Barcelona"]
```

**I tried this:**

```
    for value in CountryDict.values():
        for element in value:
            if element in CityList:
                print("Searched element: ", element)
                keyList = CountryDict.keys()
                valList = CountryDict.values()
                for searchedList in valList:
                    for stuff in searchedList:
                        if stuff == element:
                            pos = valList.index(searchedList)
                print("Key value: ", keyList[pos])
```

Comment: What's the error/problem?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter the lists based on `CityList` and the keys based on a non-null intersection.

You can use a dictionary comprehension with the walrus operator:

```
# using a set for efficiency
S = set(CityList)

out = {k: l for k,v in CountryDict.items()  # get the intersection
       if (l:=[x for x in v if x in S])}    # only if it is non-null
```

Same logic with a classical loop:

```
out = {}                                     # initialize output
for k, v in CountryDict.items():             # for each key/value
    intersection = [x for x in v if x in S]  # compute the intersection
    if intersection:                         # if it is not empty
        out[k] = v                           # add it to output
```

Output:

```
{'Spain': ['Madrid', 'Barcelona'],
 'Italy': ['Venice'],
 'UK': ['Liverpool']}
```

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward double loop is probably the easiest way to implement this albeit not necessarily the most efficient.

```
CountryDict = {
    "Spain" : ["Madrid", "Barcelona"],
    "Italy" : ["Rome", "Venice", "Milan"],
    "Germany": ["Munich"],
    "UK": ["London", "Liverpool"]
    }

CityList = ["Venice", "Liverpool", "Madrid", "Barcelona"]

output = dict()

for city in CityList:
    for k, v in CountryDict.items():
        if city in v:
            output.setdefault(k, []).append(city)

for k, v in output.items():
    print(f'{k}:')
    print(v)
    print()
```

**Output:**

```
Italy:
['Venice']

UK:
['Liverpool']

Spain:
['Madrid', 'Barcelona']
```

Or you could use a filter like this:

```
for k, v in CountryDict.items():
    if c := list(filter(lambda x: x in v, CityList)):
        output[k] = c
```

...although this is significantly slower than the simplistic double loop approach

Answer (score 0):

Your question and your post are not aligned and as @mozway already provided the answer to your post, I will answer your question (How to get the key of a specific value, in Python, if the value is an element of a list?)

Easiest way is to create a reverse dictionary that maps each city to a country. This can be done with dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> RevDict = {city: country for (country, citylist) in CountryDict.items() for city in citylist}
>>> RevDict
{'Madrid': 'Spain', 'Barcelona': 'Spain', 'Rome': 'Italy', 'Venice': 'Italy', 'Milan': 'Italy', 'Munich': 'Germany', 'London': 'UK', 'Liverpool': 'UK'}
>>> RevDict['Venice']
'Italy'
```